# Convert a list of variable in a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x

I have developed a little piece of code that I use to convert a list of variables:

```
querystring1 = 'a'
querystring2 = 'b'
querystring3 = 'c'
queries = [querystring1,querystring2,querystring3]
```

in a list of strings:

```
['querystring1', 'querystring2', 'querystring3']
```

This is the code:

```
querystring1 = 'a'
querystring2 = 'b'
querystring3 = 'c'
queries = [querystring1,querystring2,querystring3]
filenamequery = []
for query in queries:
   queryfile = [ k for k,v in locals().items() if v == query ][0]
   filenamequery.append(queryfile)
print(filenamequery)
```

Result :

```
['querystring1', 'querystring2', 'querystring3']
```

Tha bad behavior happen when I try to use my into a function:

```
def asis():
    queries = [querystring1,querystring2,querystring3]
    filenamequery = []
    for query in queries:
        queryfile = [ k for k,v in locals().items() if v == query ][0]
        filenamequery.append(queryfile)
    return filenamequery
asis()
```

Wrong results :

```
['query ', 'query ', 'query ']
```

The code I use to parse the name of the variable is not working (queryfile), and I don´t know why.
Any clue will be appreciated

Comment: When using it in the function, try using `globals` instead of `locals`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was the scope

```
queryfile = [ k for k,v in locals().items() if v == query ][0]
```

by

```
queryfile = [ k for k,v in globals().items() if v == query ][0]
```